# optimization function in R that can accept objective, gradient, AND hessian?

Tags: r, package, mathematical-optimization

I have a complex objective function I am looking to optimize. The optimization problem takes a considerable time to optimize. Fortunately, I do have the gradient and the hessian of the function available.

Is there an optimization package in R that can take all three of these inputs? The class 'optim' does not accept the Hessian. I have scanned the [CRAN task page for optimization](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) and nothing pops.

For what it's worth, I am able to perform the optimization in MATLAB using '[fminunc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/optim/ug/fminunc.html)' with the  the 'GradObj' and 'Hessian' arguments.

Comment: check the `trust` package (http://goo.gl/HHHN1). it accepts a function that computes the `objective`, `gradient` and `hessian`. and if i recall correctly, it uses the same algorithm used by `fminunc`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the package [`trust`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trust/index.html) which does trust region optimization will do the trick. From the documentation of [`trust`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trust/index.html), you see that

> This function carries out a minimization or maximization of a function
>   using a trust region algorithm... (it accepts) an R function that
>   computes value, gradient, and Hessian of the function to be minimized
>   or maximized and returns them as a list with components value,
>   gradient, and hessian.

In fact, I think it uses the same algorithm used by `fminunc`.

> By default `fminunc` chooses the large-scale algorithm if you supply the
>   gradient in fun and set GradObj to 'on' using optimset. This algorithm
>   is a subspace trust-region method and is based on the
>   interior-reflective Newton method described in [2] and [3]. Each
>   iteration involves the approximate solution of a large linear system
>   using the method of preconditioned conjugate gradients (PCG). See
>   Large Scale fminunc Algorithm, Trust-Region Methods for Nonlinear
>   Minimization and Preconditioned Conjugate Gradient Method.

Answer (score 1):

Both `stats::nlm()` and `stats::nlminb()` take analytical gradients and hessians. Note, however, that the former (`nlm()`) currently [does not update the analytical gradient correctly](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=17249) but that this is fixed in the current development version of R (since R-devel, svn rev 72555).